# How do I mount a disk drive using fabric

Tags: fabric

I have been trying to use this commands in fabric to mount a disk, but my following code is not working

```
sudo('echo "g\r\
n\r\
1\r\
\r\
\r\
w\r\
"|fdisk /dev/xvdb', pty=False)
sudo("mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb", pty=False)
sudo("mkdir -p /mnt/couchbase")
append('/etc/fstab',"/dev/xvdb1 /mnt/couchbase ext4 defaults         0     0", use_sudo=True)
sudo('mount /mnt/couchbase')
```

Any idea how can I improve on this?

Comment: What does "is not working" does exactly mean?

Comment: when i ssh into the VM, the disk is not mounted. How do I mount a disk using fabric?

Comment: Which output do you get if you run your code?

Comment: this is the output

Warning:"|fdisk /dev/xvdb'!nzero return code 1 while executing 'echo "g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an answer to this

```
sudo('echo "g\r\n\
    n\r\n\
    1\r\n\
    %s\r\n\
    %s\r\n\
    "|fdisk /dev/xvdb' %('\n', '\n'))
```